# Do something on every Celery Task run

Tags: python, celery

Assume I have some Celery tasks which are based on one abstract task.

```
class BaseTask(Task):
    abstract = True

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        logging.info('Task failed')

    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        logging.info('Task success')

    # NO SUCH METHOD IN TASK
    # def on_start(self):
    #     do_something_on_every_task_start()

@app.task(base=BaseTask)
def task1(x):
    print x

@app.task(base=BaseTask)
def task2(y):
    print y
```

I want to do something on start of every task execution. Are there any possibilities to achieve this result? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can override the `__call__` method. This will work both if you call the task synchronously with `task1(1)` or call it asynchronously, with `task1.delay(1)`. In the following example, you'll get "CALLED!" on the console or in the logs depending on how you call the task and how your logging is setup.

```
class BaseTask(Task):
    abstract = True

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "CALLED!"
        return super(BaseTask, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

@app.task(base=BaseTask)
def task1(x):
    print x

@app.task(base=BaseTask)
def task2(y):
    print y
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer. I think it's correct, but I'm wondering why there is no semantically more beautiful method to do this provided from the celery project...

Answer (score 2):

If need 'semantically beautiful' method, you can try signals.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html

Here is another useful post on pre/post task callbacks.

https://gist.github.com/nuria/35f332acfb84ecf80e3b